# relative path - absolute path not working?

Tags: css, path

I have a css file that links to some images for a slider and i want to change the relative path to an absolute path

```
 background: url(../img/bg.png) no-repeat 0 0;
```

I have used the below as the img folder is in the root folder of the site but it doesn't work.  Is there something I am missing here?  When I copy the image to the images folder and use images/bp.png is doesnt work either?

```
background: url(img/bg.png) no-repeat 0 0;
```

I've tried

```
background: url(/img/bg.png) no-repeat 0 0; and it still doesn't work
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, to get to the root your CSS should look like this

```
background: url(/img/bg.png) no-repeat 0 0;
```

The slash at the beginning of the URL will take you to the root. Without the slash its looking for the image in the same folder where your CSS file resides

Comment: My answer is correct, that is how to use an image from the img folder in the root of your site. Are you sure the folder is in the website root? And does the bg.png image exist? Does your site have  .htaccess file in the root?

Comment: Yes the folder is called img and is in the root folder.  Yes the bg.png exists.  Htaccess file?

Comment: Are you viewing your webpage on a local server, e.g http://localhost/test.html or are you simply viewing the html file in a browser e.g. file:///private/var/www/my-website/test.html

Comment: the site isn't live yet.  I'm just viewing the html file in a browser

Comment: Well if you are just viewing your html file in a browser with a URL such as file:///private/var/www/my-website/test.html, then the root is going to be the root of your computer. You need to set up a local testing server on your computer, and view your html file using a test URL

Comment: the site is now live and in the root folder there is a folder called 'img'.  I changed the css file from                            background: url(../img/left.png) no-repeat left center; to      background: url(/img/left.png) no-repeat left center;    and the images disappear?

Comment: Can you send a link to your live site?

Comment: If I edit your CSS in firebug to the following, .SliderNamePrev_2 {background: url("/img/left.png") no-repeat left center; } the left arrow image still shows up. I think should be marked as closed

Comment: I edited the css file to   .SliderNamePrev_2 {
 background: url("/img/left.png") no-repeat left center;   but it still disappears

Comment: when I use (/img/left.png) I can still click the left arrow and it moves the slider to the next image, I just can't see the left.png image